# The project is using an unsupported version of Gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I am following [this](https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/android/native/new) tutorial in Android Studio.

When trying to Import the project, I get a dialog saying:

"**The project is using an unsupported version of Gradle."
Please point to a supported Gradle version in the project's Gradle settings or in the project's Gradle wrapper (if applicable.)**"

It also fails if I select the *wrapper* method by stating:
"**Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found**.

Here is what Parse's gradle looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral() }

dependencies {
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.1.3'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar') }

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    } 
}
```

My project's Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "id.goes.here"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    } }

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) 
}
```

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you running? Are you using the Gradle wrapper? If so, what version of Gradle are you using? This is set in /gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties.

Comment: I am using Android Studio 8.14. I believe I am using Gradle Wrapper, yes. I'll update my question showing my own Gradle.

Comment: @Tanis.7x Please check my question. I have updated it.

Answer (score 11):

You generally have two build.gradles in your project:

- A top level build.gradle in your project's root that contains `buildscript {}` and `allprojects {}` sections. This contains the project-wide configuration.
- An app module build.gradle (located in your app's module folder) that contains the configuration for your android application. This one contains the `android {}` section.

Open up your top level build.gradle, and look at the Android Gradle plugin version (it will look something like `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0-rc3'`).

If the plugin is at version 0.13.0 or higher, you need to make sure you are using Gradle 2.1 or newer.
If the plugin is below version 0.14.4, you cannot use Gradle 2.2+.

Before going further, you need to find out whether you are using a local gradle distribution or the wrapper. To do so, go to File > Settings, then search for "Gradle." If "Use local Gradle distribution" is selected, either update your local Gradle to a supported version or switch to using the wrapper.

If you are using the wrapper, the configuration for the Gradle version is located under `<your-project>/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`. This file contains a line that will look something like this: `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip`
. Simply change the version at the end to  a supported version.

Studio typically will offer to update the wrapper for you if you click on the error telling you that it is not a supported version.

Comment: How do I know what version Parse is using? When I downloaded the SDK, it doesn't say what version it uses. Nor in the root OR the app specific Gradle.

Comment: Parse isn't using any version of Gradle. The only time the version of Gradle itself matters is when you build your project.

Comment: if you can't find the gradle folder just copy paste it from another project (crate new project and then copy past the gradle folder)

Answer (score 1):

I resolve this issue by syncing project with gradle files.

In android studio from menu open File option and click option sync project with gradle files.

Comment: This worked for me after a mac OS upgrade to Big Sur. After this and a clean in terminal the app was working fine, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

In the project build,gradle file
Replace

```
runProguard false
```

With

```
minifyEnabled true
```