# Resolving and preventing "The project is using an unsupported version of Gradle" when opening a project

Tags: gradle, android-studio

I cloned a project from github and want to open it in android studio 1.  The "Import Project from Gradle" window has "Use default gradle wrapper(not configured for the current project)" greyed out, so I select "Use local gradle distribution".  Pressing OK shows this error dialog: "The project is using an unsupported version of gradle".

[The project is using an unsupported version of Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27361337/the-project-is-using-an-unsupported-version-of-gradle) says to check the project's build.gradle and use that:

1. I can download that gradle version and point to it, but what is the best practice when collaborating on a project and dealing with different gradle versions?  Is it for everyone to use the gradle wrapper script so that everyone uses the same gradle version?
2. In my scenario the cloned project does not contain a gradle wrapper.  Should I copy it from another project and edit the gradle version to the one supported by this cloned project?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you need to manually update the `build.gradle` files and then try again. Start with the top level `build.gradle` and `settings.gradle` files, check the buildScript gradle value. Then work through the `build.gradle` files in each module. If they don't exist you can create a basic version for each module.

Each project checked in should contain build.gradle files, settings.gradle and the gradle/wrapper folder. From there anyone should be able to import and build the project.

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}
```