# Build failed due to exception

Tags: flutter, exception, gradle, build.gradle

I can't take build from one of the existing projects and it shows an error like this while running 'flutter build apk'

Exception: [!] Your app is using an unsupported Gradle project. To fix this problem, create a new project by running `flutter create -t app     <app-directory>` and then move the dart code, assets and pubspec.yaml to the new project.

I tried copying the lib, assets, pubspec.yaml file all the dart files to a newly created file, but it still shows the same error when running the command.

Comment: this may look too much, create a new project then copy paste the code. everything things will be up-to-date.

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62064188/8144311